# Excel web data from password protected site (password not required after first login)

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA script that goes to a website I maintain with a table of data and updates a range with the data on the website. The website is password protected. I have the whole VBA script figured out except for one piece: if the password has already been input and the browser saves a cookie, the VBA script fails because it tries to input a value into a form that doesn't exist. I need to create an if statement that checks if the form that catches the password exists - and if it doesn't, skips the section of code that puts the password into the form.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "http://google.com/"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
MsgBox ieDoc.getElementById("pwbox-106")

If ieDoc.getElementById("pwbox-106") <> Null Then
   With ieDoc.forms("The form that accepts and submits password")
    .post_password.Value = "PASSWORD"
    .submit
End With

End If

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("tablepress-1")

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet2.Select
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet2.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close IE
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim el

Set el = ieDoc.getElementById("pwbox-106")

If Not el Is Nothing Then
   With ieDoc.forms("The form that accepts and submits password")
    .post_password.Value = "PASSWORD"
    .submit
   End With
End If
```

Don't forget that if/after you submit the form, you will need to wait for the document to load before trying to get a reference to the table you want to use.