# How to get web data from password protected site?

Tags: excel, vba

**Goals:**
Pull data from a password protected website.
Make it where credentials don't need to be entered every time.
Have it be in an xlsm template that others can easily make a copy of and use without any extra setup steps.

**Current Method:**
Enable legacy "From Web" method.
Have anyone who wants to use it follow a procedure to open the legacy "From Web" wizard, browse to the intranet site, and enter their username and password.
After that, the code below works great:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://Website.intranet.com/allsites/", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "RFCMarket"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Though I still need to clean up any extra/unnecessary settings there and if possible, maybe add filtering to only pull a subset of the data from the web table into excel.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried the modern "From web" and ran into the same issues as others where it seems to be broken. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/unable-to-connect-to-web-source-with-credentials-in-power-query/m-p/100748
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/unable-to-connect-to-web-source-with-credentials-in-power-query/m-p/100748
I've tried putting the username and password into the url with no success https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

**Request:**
Is there a way to do that manual legacy from web login process through vba?
Or some other way to pass username/password?
I haven't tried something like this yet [Excel web data from password protected site (password not required after first login)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941877/excel-web-data-from-password-protected-site-password-not-required-after-first-l) as it has tons of things I don't understand since I know basically nothing about html.

Comment: browser automation?

Comment: @QHarr That is the only way left I see, however weighing the two, I'd rather first time users have to follow a one time setup procedure than to go through however much time it will take for me to figure out all the components of browser automation as well as securely saving/managing passwords in excel. Especially since for security reasons, it would need to be made where those credentials aren't usable on someone else's computer. I guess that part wouldn't be too hard, it would just be picking a location local to the computer to save an encrypted file.